# Missing step in showing that $\sqrt{|x|} \sin(\sqrt{|x|})$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I'm studying for some exams and this was one of my practice questions. I am asked to show that $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|} \sin(\sqrt{|x|})$ is uniformly continuous on ${\bf R}$. I started by observing that on $(0, \infty)$, we have $f(x) = \sqrt x \sin (\sqrt x)$, and so on this domain we have

$$f'(x) = {1\over 2} \cos(\sqrt x) + {1\over 2\sqrt x} \sin(\sqrt x).$$

This is easily seen to be bounded, since $|\cos(x)| \le 1$ and $\sin x \le x$. Thus $f$ is Lipschitz on $(0,\infty)$ and hence uniformly continuous on that domain. By a symmetric argument, $f$ is also Lipschitz on $(-\infty, 0)$.

Now it's clear that $f$ is continuous on ${\bf R}$, and we have just shown that it is uniformly continuous on ${\bf R}\setminus \{0\}$. Does this immediately imply that $f$ is uniformly continuous on all of ${\bf R}$? I want to say yes but cannot think of any argument that isn't handwavy in some way. The intuition being that if we know a continuous function to be uniformly continuous on all but a set of measure zero, then we can't possibly have unbounded slope anywhere since there's not "enough" domain on which to create such a segment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more grounded version : You have shown that the whole thing is $1$-Lipschitz on $\mathbb R^*$. Let's show it's also the case on $\mathbb R$.

Let $x, y \in \mathbb R$.

If $x,y\neq 0$ then $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y|$ by virtue of the work already done.

If $x=0$ and $y=0$, this is obvious.

If $x\neq 0$ and $y=0$ then $|f(x)-f(y)| = |f(x)| \leq |x| = |x-y|$ because of the bound on $\sin$ you already talked about.

The remaining case is symmetric.

All done.

Comment: Accepting this answer for its simplicity and completeness, though the other answer also works, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon /2$ if $|x-y| <\delta$ and $x\neq 0, y \neq 0$. By taking limit as $ x \to 0$ and/or $y \to 0$ in this inequality (and using continuity of $f$) we see that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \epsilon /2$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb R$ with $|x-y| <\delta$.

Comment: the last part should be rephrased for clarity: the inequality is for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is that if $f$ is continuous in a metric space and uniformly continuous on a dense subspace, then it's uniformly continuous on the whole space. I have no reference that I can think of, but you can just generalize the proof given in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for this comment about the general case (and for pointing out to me that the general case has nothing to do with measure and instead has to do with density). I suppose that we'd need some $\epsilon / 3$ argument, instead of $\epsilon/2$, if the complement is not a singleton as it is in the case of ${\bf R}^*$.

Comment: You're right, though there's no obligation to cut the $\epsilon$ in equal parts. That allows you to show that the modulus of uniform continuity is the same as the one restricted to the dense subspace.